# Use of ResourseBundle in iReport

Tags: ireport

In iReport I am using the Internationalization using resourseBundle properties file.. But i have noticed that these  properties files are placed in classpath of ireport....

My query is I want those files to b placed ***somewhere out in other location*** except the class path of ireport and use the same properties file(which are placed outside) in iReport ....
Can i achieve it?
please do help.

Comment: Please ask if you are unclear with question so that i will tr to explain much precisely....